# Why is my ip_address[] being overwritten?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip-address

I am trying to write a server/client code and everything is working correctly, except when I am trying to store the IP addresses of incoming and outgoing connections.

```
getpeername(new_fd[client],(struct sockaddr*) &client_addr[client],&addr_size);
ip_address[client] = inet_ntoa(client_addr[client].sin_addr);
```

In this case, when a connection is established, the content of every index would be changed to the lastest connection made. So every cell of ip_address[] will contain the lastest connection's IP address.
What can the problem be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` generally looks something like this:

```
char *
inet_ntoa(struct in_addr ina)
{
    static char buf[some_size];
    /* a series of sprintfs */
    return bufl
}
```

Which means on every call the contents of `buf` are going to be rewritten. Obviously you can't use the return value of `inet_ntoa` directly; you would have to use `memcpy` or something like that.

#### Real solution

Use [`inet_ntop`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html) instead. It's newer, supports IPv6 out of the box and should be thread-safe (oh yeah, `inet_ntoa` isn't).

Answer (score 2):

inet_ntoa does not allocate. It returns a static buffer. You need to copy it into your own storage if you want to keep the string.

Comment: which is clearly stated in the man: "inet_ntoa() returns the dots-and-numbers string in a static buffer that is overwritten with each call to the function."